# Which is the better data type for storing monetary values in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, currency, currency-formatting, fieldtype

In Sharepoint 2010, the "field types" (data types) for list items that could presumably be used for monetary values are Decimal and Currency. Normally, decimal is the preferred data type in C# for money.

But what of this Currency type? Based on its name, it seems it may be the more suitable of the two. Is it?

I could also use integer (where 1225 represents $12.25, for instance) or String (where "12.25" represents $12.25), but the first two mentioned (Decimal and Currency) would seem to be the best bets.

### UPDATE

Oddly enough, I was going to provisionally go with "Decimal" in my list, but SPFieldType actually doesn't seem to have a Decimal member available, so for now I'm going with Currency. According to page p. 230 of "Inside MS Sharepoint 2010," though, Decimal is one of the types...???

Comment: Does it have a `NUMBER` or `NUMERIC` type? In the SQL world they're the same as `DECIMAL`. If the value is ultimately going to SQL Server then be advised the `CURRENCY` data type has four decimal places; not sure how well SharePoint (I'm not an expert) will handle formatting it for you. But definitely don't use integer/string if you'll be doing any calculations; you'll end up doing a lot of hacking.

Comment: Yes, there is a "Number" data type.

Comment: Oops - I just looked up the SharePoint `NUMBER` type and it actually looks like a floating point rather than a SQL-type number/numeric/decimal. A floating point can have rounding and accuracy issues (though normally only with very large numbers) but given that it's an inexact type I'd probably rule it out and go with `CURRENCY`.